# How to display a score count, displaying times it has been randomly generated?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a text 'game', which has 3 players, whose names are in an array and I'm trying to set up a score count so that each time their name is randomly generated after pressing a button, it is added to their personal score count.

As this is my first project I haven't had any success on any methods.

```
var playerOne = prompt("Enter the name of the 1st player");
var playerTwo = prompt("Enter the name of the 2nd player"); 
var playerThree = prompt("Enter the name of the 3rd player");  

const playerName = [playerOne, playerTwo, playerThree];
const didHow = ['quietly', 'carefully', 'slowly', 'quickly', 'secretly', 'ragefully'];
const didWhat = ['went', 'ran', 'fell', 'drove', 'jumped', 'fought', 'died'];



const quoteBtn = document.querySelector('#quoteBtn');
const playerNameQ = document.querySelector('#playerName');
const didHowQ = document.querySelector('#didHow');
const didWhatQ = document.querySelector('#didWhat');



quoteBtn.addEventListener('click', displayQuote);

function displayQuote() {
    let numberOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*playerName.length);
    let numberTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*didHow.length);
    let numberThree = Math.floor(Math.random()*didWhat.length);



    playerNameQ.innerHTML = playerName[numberOne];
    didHowQ.innerHTML = didHow[numberTwo];
    didWhatQ.innerHTML = didWhat[numberThree];
}
```

Comment: So when when a user enters their name, set their score to -1? Be more specific with what you want. What errors are you getting? What problem do you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by putting:

```
var pointsOne = 0;
var pointsTwo = 0;
var pointsThree = 0;
```

before displayQuote() and by inserting the following code in the function:

```
    if (playerName[numberOne] == playerOne) {
        pointsOne++;
        pointsOnee.innerHTML = pointsOne;
    }
    else if (playerName[numberOne] == playerTwo) {
        pointsTwo++;
        pointsTwoo.innerHTML = pointsTwo;
    }
    else if (playerName[numberOne] == playerThree){
        pointsThree++;
        pointsThreee.innerHTML = pointsThree;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not a compiled language and is interpreted. I.e., order of declarations matter. This is less true when you get into classes, but for your example specifically, move your function declaration before you use it:

```
...

function displayQuote() {
    // ...
}

quoteBtn.addEventListener('click', displayQuote);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of objects for each user,

```
arrUsers=[{
"id":"1"
"user":"user1",
"score":0
},{
"id":"2"
"user":"user2",
"score":0
},{
"id":"3"
"user":"user3",
"score":0
}]
```

After this, check the turn of the player with the id, and each time it press the button do score++.